# How can I switch from Win/Fedora to Win/Kubuntu dual boot

Tags: windows, linux, fedora, multi-boot, kubuntu

I've got a desktop system with WinXP and an and older Fedora.
Things work ok, BUT
I'd like to change to Kubuntu 12.10 - which I use at work.

The install dvd apparently suggests that I shrink the windows partition and put Kubuntu in the freed space, but I'd rather drop the Fedora installation completely - without losing Windows.
I'm not familiar enough with manually specifying the partitions to be confident in doing that.

Any suggestions, or resources that would walk me through things?

Comment: select the fedora partition during install and it will replace the OS and format the partition. if any problems come out of that, just grub-update, or add a chainloader to your grub